# How to automatically display date of creation

Tags: notion

I would like to know if there is a way to create a property in a Notion database that automatically displays the creation date of the entry. The function

> now( )

works, but only if I don't modify the entry. It shows me the date of last edit but I want the creation date. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to create a custom type for this; Notion already saves this information. Just use the "Created time" property type.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Please accept.